# How to pythonically make a total count of all counts in a list of objects?

Tags: python, python-2.7, count

I've got a list of objects which have a `.count()` method. I now want a total count of all objects. The following works:

```
count = 0
for the_obj in obj_list:
    count += the_obj.count()
print count
```

but I've got the feeling that there are more Pythonic ways of doing this. Anybody have a tip?

Comment: You can do `sum(obj.count() for obj in obj_list)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) with a generator to sum the individual counts.

```
count = sum(obj.count() for obj in obj_list)
```

Alternatively (*although not necessary*), a functional approach would be to use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), with [`methodcaller`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.methodcaller) to call the method.

```
from operator import add, methodcaller
count = reduce(add, map(methodcaller('count'), obj_list))
```

Comment: concise and clear answer, perfectly explained with the better alternatives, love this answer